# Changing mouse over Foreground color of controls inside a Button in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I've got this bit of XAML code. What it does is override the style of a button when mousing over. Here I use Green and PaleGreen for the sake of simplicity.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="someNameHere">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleGreen"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works on both a standard button and more exotic ones, like so:

```
    <Button Name="Standard" Content="Test" Style="{DynamicResource someNameHere}"/>
    <Button Name="Exotic" Style="{DynamicResource someNameHere}">
        <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="MoreExotic" Style="{DynamicResource someNameHere}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

I want to do the same thing in code behind, on a custom button class. This is the code I have this far:

```
public class FlatButton : Button
{
    public FlatButton() : base()
    {
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(2, 0, 0, 0);
        SetStyle();
    }
    
    private void SetStyle()
    {
        Background = Brushes.PaleGreen;
        Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;

        Style style = new Style(typeof(Button), Style);

        ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));
        FrameworkElementFactory border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
        border.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(Button.BackgroundProperty));
        border.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, BorderBrush);
        border.SetValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, BorderThickness);
        border.Name = "someNameHere";
        template.VisualTree = border;

        FrameworkElementFactory content = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
        content.SetValue(Border.VerticalAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center);
        content.SetValue(Border.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        border.AppendChild(content);

        Trigger trigger = new Trigger()
        {
            Property = Button.IsMouseOverProperty,
            Value = true
        };

        trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter()
        {
            TargetName = "someNameHere",
            Property = Button.BackgroundProperty,
            Value = Brushes.Green
        });
        trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter()
        {
            TargetName = "someNameHere",
            Property = Button.ForegroundProperty,
            Value = Brushes.White
        });
        template.Triggers.Add(trigger);

        Setter setter = new Setter()
        {
            Property = Button.TemplateProperty,
            Value = template
        };

        style.Setters.Add(setter);
        Style = style;
    }
```

And applying it to a similar set of buttons:

```
<local:FlatButton x:Name="Standard" Content="Test"/>
<local:FlatButton x:Name="Exotic">
    <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
</local:FlatButton>
<local:FlatButton x:Name="MoreExotic">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</local:FlatButton>
```

The problem is this works fine on the "standard" button, but it doesn't change the Foreground color of the elements inside the "exotic" buttons like the XAML version does, and I haven't been able to find a solution so far.

So does anyone know how do I set the Foreground color of my content in code?

The three use cases I'm interested in are plaintext, TextBlock, and TextBlock inside a container like a Grid or StackPanel.

Comment: You should really do that from XAML instead.

Comment: @aybe I can already do it in XAML. That's not what I'm after.

Comment: Your whole approach is wrong, there is simply no need to do any code behind for what you're looking for. As you've already realized, it's very convoluted to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Style` that you are creating programmatically is not equivalent to the one you have defined in the XAML markup. This is:

```
private void SetStyle()
{
    Style style = new Style(typeof(Button), Style);

    ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));
    FrameworkElementFactory border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
    border.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(Button.BackgroundProperty));
    border.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Green);
    border.SetValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(2, 0, 0, 0));
    template.VisualTree = border;

    FrameworkElementFactory content = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
    content.SetValue(Border.VerticalAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center);
    content.SetValue(Border.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center);
    border.AppendChild(content);

    style.Setters.Add(new Setter()
    {
        Property = Button.BackgroundProperty,
        Value = Brushes.PaleGreen
    });

    style.Setters.Add(new Setter()
    {
        Property = Button.ForegroundProperty,
        Value = Brushes.Black
    });

    Trigger trigger = new Trigger()
    {
        Property = Button.IsMouseOverProperty,
        Value = true
    };

    trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter()
    {
        Property = Button.BackgroundProperty,
        Value = Brushes.Green
    });
    trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter()
    {
        Property = TextBlock.ForegroundProperty,
        Value = Brushes.White
    });
    template.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    Setter setter = new Setter()
    {
        Property = Button.TemplateProperty,
        Value = template
    };

    style.Setters.Add(setter);
    Style = style;
}
```

Comment: Can confirm, this works like my original XAML. Thanks for the help